# How to reverse order DirectoryIterator

Tags: php

Here is i am using this code for directory indexing , now problem in this code , i want sort it in reverse order , Example it shows 1. Directory one , 2. Directory 2 , 3. Directory 3 . But i want this in reverse order - Here is my code

```
<?php $path='files'; foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
if ($file->isDot()) continue;

if ($file->isDir()) {
    $filname=$file->getFilename();
    $filname=str_replace(' ','-',$filname);
    echo '<div class="catRow"><a href="http://'.$sitenameurl.'/category/'.$filname.'.html"><div>&#187; '.$file->getFilename().'</div></a></div>';
}} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do it by setting a specific option or setting.
However, since all you want to do it just to reverse the order you can store the data in an array and then simply reverse the array.

```
<?php
$filesArr = array();
$path='files';
$Iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);

foreach ($Iterator as $file) {
 if ($file->isDot()) continue;

 if ($file->isDir()) {
      $filname=$file->getFilename();
      $filname=str_replace(' ','-',$filname);
      $filesArr[] = '<div class="catRow"><a href="http://'.$sitenameurl.'/category/'.$filname.'.html"><div>&#187; '.$file->getFilename().'</div></a></div>';
 }
}

$revFilesArr = array_reverse($filesArr);
foreach($revFilesArr as $fileRow){
  echo $fileRow;
}
?>
```